# How to create multilanguage MODx website with unique articles in each language?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, babeljs

I need ti develop multilanguage webiste with (russian, english and kyrgyz languages), each article has version only in one language.

Can you please help me with questions: 
1. how to create context for kyrgyz language? is it just put `culturekey=kg`?
2. how to translate oarts of chunks, i.e "***comments***" or ***buttons***? do I need to create different chunks for new contexts? Or I simply save translation somewhere?
3. how to control which resources will be shown through pdoresources (getresources)? do I need to put id from all contexts?
4. for context web — pages has alias mywebsite.ru/category/article, but for "en" context — `mywebsite.ru/en/INDEX/category/article`. how to remove index? when i try to use link like `mywebsite.ru/en/` — it shows 503 error. what can be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create new context
   [image]
2. Use [lexicon](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/advanced-development/internationalization) entry. If you don't want to create a new namespace, just use **core**.
3. If you read the [documentation](https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources), you can see the available parameters to define the parent, resources, or excluded resources to show.
4. You need to check your .htaccess and all [friendly URL settings](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/using-friendly-urls). 503 itself means unavailable site. Check your system settings, and search for **site_status** key. It should be "yes" for a running website.

Comment: thanks! honestly I already found solution, but still your answer is correct